# Specify that a method argument must inherit from one class and implement an interface

Tags: java, android

I am writing a method which requires that one of its arguments descend from a particular class (`MyClass`) and implement an interface (`MyInterface`).

A crude way of doing this would be

```
public void doStuff(MyClass arg0) {
    if (!(arg0 instanceof MyInterface))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arg0 must implement MyInterface");
    // do whatever we need to do
}
```

Note that `MyClass` does not implement `MyInterface`, and both are classes that I import as they are.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this, preferably one that would already flag errors at build time?

Comment: what about `public void doStuff(MyInterface someclass)`? Then just make MyClass implements MyInterface?

Comment: @blahfunk Both classes are just imports, so that is not an option. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the following generic method:

```
public <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> void doStuff(T arg) { ... }
```

Assuming the following classes (and interfaces)

```
class MyClass {}
interface MyInterface {}

class A extends MyClass {}
class B implements MyInterface {}
class C extends MyClass implements MyInterface {}
```

the following two statements are illegal (compiler error)

```
doStuff(new A());
doStuff(new B());
```

whereas the following statement will compile

```
doStuff(new C());
```

See [JLS §4.4 (Type Variables)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) for more information about the somehwat weird type variable declaration.

Comment: Depending on the code structure, you may be able to just do `void doStuff(C arg)`

Comment: Well ... if other classes also extend that class and implement that interface, it will not work.

Comment: Well, you could just make those other classes `extend C`, but that may not be possible for the OP, hence why it's "depending on the code structure"

Comment: Exactly... thanks for the solution, this is what I looked for. I realize I should have called the classes `SomeoneElsesClass` and `SomeoneElsesInterface`, respectively....